# Given data per second, how can I make a seamless web chart of some rolling period of time?

Tags: graphics

So lets say I have 24 hours of data split into 1 hour chunks, and the data is per second sequentially. I want to graph a rolling hour at a time, such that every second for the user, the graph will update to reflect an hour of data. I want this to look as seamless as possible.

I guess there are two questions here: one is how do you do the physical drawing of the data? The second is: how can you progressively load files? I assume that you would load hour 1 and hour 2 at first, chart hour 1, then sort of "queue" the seconds in hour 2 and take an element and draw it every second. At some point you have to load the next hour of data and continue the process...not really sure how to do this in a web context.

I appreciate the help!